# How to retrieve an Sql decimal(18,3) column in Vbscript

Tags: vbscript, ado, hp-uft

I did a fair amount of research on this issue but can't get my head around a solution. Here's the problem:

Using HP UFT I read a column value from an ADO recordset with Vbscript. This column is a decimal(18,3) and vbScript recognises the decimal datatype (VarType).

Retrieving the value to vbScript results in a VbDouble variable with precision 15. Thus losing the decimal places.

Can anyone help me to retrieve all 18 digits?

My code & what I tried:
In below code I read the recordset value and created portions that attempt to resolve this. None of them work.

```
Dim OdbcDSN
Dim connect, sql, resultSet

OdbcDSN = "DSN=CLAV;UID=UFT;PWD=UFT"
Set connect = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
connect.Open OdbcDSN

sql="select Mfr0335BtrTrxBdr from MFR0335"
'--> contains 123456789012345.123

Set resultSet = connect.Execute(sql)
On Error Resume Next
resultSet.MoveFirst

wscript.echo "getstring: " & resultSet.getstring()
'--> 123456789012345    

resultSet.MoveFirst

With resultSet.fields.item("Mfr0335BtrTrxBdr")

    wscript.echo "-------value & type -------------"
    wscript.echo .value
    '--> 123456789012345    
    wscript.echo "datatype rs column = " & .type
    '--> 131 (adNumeric ADO datatype)   
    wscript.echo "datatype read by vbscript = " & vartype(.value)   
    '--> 14 (VbDecimal) 
    wscript.echo "length = " & len(.value)
    '--> 15 

    wscript.echo "------- conversion -------------"
    wscript.echo "cStr: " & cstr(.value)
    '--> 123456789012345
    wscript.echo "formatnumber: " & formatnumber(.value, 3, 0, 0, 0)
    '--> 123456789012345.000

    wscript.echo "-------assign value to variable ------"       
    myVar = .value  
    wscript.echo "myVar: " & myVar
    '--> 123456789012345    
    wscript.echo "vartype: " & vartype(myVar)       
    '--> VbDouble   

    wscript.echo "-------convert Vbdecimal to string?----"
    err.clear
    myVar = cstr(.value)
    wscript.echo "vartype: " & vartype(myVar)
    '--> 8 (VbString)
    wscript.echo "myVar: " & (myVar)
    '--> 123456789012345

    wscript.echo "-------is equal to it's decimal value?---"
    err.clear
    wscript.echo .value = 123456789012345.123
    '--> (no value)
    wscript.echo err.description
    '--> Type mismatch
    wscript.echo vartype(123456789012345.123)       
    '--> VbDouble       

    wscript.echo "--------do calculation with decimal values-----"
    err.clear       
    wscript.echo 123456789012345.123 - 123000000000000.0
    '--> 456789012345.125
    wscript.echo vartype(123456789012345.123 - 123000000000000.0)
    '--> Vbdouble   

    resultSet.MoveNext

 end with
resultSet.Close
connect.Close
Set connect = Nothing

WScript.Quit(0)
```

output:

```
getstring: 123456789012345

-------value & type -------------
123456789012345
datatype rs column = 131
datatype read by vbscript = 14
length = 15
------- conversion -------------
cStr: 123456789012345
formatnumber: 123456789012345.000
-------assign value to variable ------
myVar: 123456789012345
vartype: 14
-------convert Vbdecimal to string?----
vartype: 8
myVar: 123456789012345
-------is equal to it's decimal value?---
Type mismatch
5
--------do calculation with decimal values-----
456789012345.125
5
```

Comment: Of what SQL type is Mfr0335BtrTrxBdr in the table?

Comment: @TheBlastOne the OP already said in the question the column is `decimal(18, 3)` in SQL.

Comment: resultSet.fields.item("Mfr0335BtrTrxBdr").type = 131 (adNumeric, Indicates an exact numeric value with a fixed precision and scale)

Comment: In case someone suggests this, I tried casting but this is not supported by the provider.

"Select CAST(Mfr0335BtrTrxBdr AS varchar(18)) from MFR0335"